# Unable to install ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble installing ggplot2 into R. I've looked around here and haven't seen the same error that I'm getting.

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dep=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.13.1/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) : 
  unable to install packages

Can anybody help?
```

Comment: I don't know why, but your `lib` env variable points to `Program Files`, and programs are not allowed to write to that directory after installation, it requires admin rights and is considered a bad practice. Normally, you'd point your lib somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: In my case, the lib is `C:/Users/username/R/win-library/2.13`

Comment: There is no programming question here. Get help from your local sysadmin, and/or read the R FAQ and 'R Installation + Admininstration'.

Answer (score 7):

It would actually suffice to invoke as follows:

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dep=TRUE, lib=NULL)
```

and R should substitue `lib` with the default location, as in my comment.

Or you could change the environment variable itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, I tried your suggestion and got the same error. How do I change the environment variable? I just installed R on the computer I'm using, could I have done something wrong when I installed R on my computer?

Comment: Than you should create the directory for R libs, for example using the path I use, and supply it's path as a value for the `lib` argument. And after that, follow Dirk's advice :)

Answer (score 3):

R needs to have write access to your library to install a package there. The other advice you're getting is good and should be preferred, but you can run R (or RStudio) as an administrator (right-click on the .exe and "Run as Administrator" is an option) which should give it write access to your library.

Answer (score -1):

In **RStudio**:

- Try going to "*Tools*";
- At the top you have "*Install packages*", click on that;
- Then click on "*Install to Library*", change that to another library and save there.